# Connect to another database in stored procedure - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have two database in a same DB server. But both the database use different user name and password. I have a stored procedure in oue second databse that should connect to first database and pull some records?

Is this feasible?

Earlier both of our database were using same username and password. so it was easy for us to connect between datbase in stored procedure. But now we changed the password.

We are using SQL Server 2008 DB

Answer (score 0):

Without mapping your database users to the same server login, your options are very limited. A good option is to take another look at how cross-database ownership chaining works. You probably were already using cross-database ownership chaining, as discussed in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

> SQL Server can be configured to allow ownership chaining between specific databases or across all databases inside a single instance of SQL Server. Cross-database ownership chaining is disabled by default, and should not be enabled unless it is specifically required.

If cross-database ownership chaining is not an option, an ugly option would be to use `OpenRowset`. Details are in [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).